Preserve field optional-ness using conditional and mapped type
The following type removes desired properties from all nested depths of the input type:
type DeepRemoveProps<T, P extends string> = T extends object
  ? { [K in Exclude<keyof T, P>]: DeepRemoveProps<T[K], P> }
  : T;

For example:
type Input = {
  a: {
    b: string,
    c: {
      xx: 'removed',
      d: string
    }
  },
  yy: { removed: true },
  xx: 'im removed'
};
type Result = DeepRemoveProps<Input, 'xx' | 'yy'>;

In this case Result resolves to:
type Result = {
  a: {
    b: string,
    c: {
      d: string
    }
  }
};

But this type fails to preserve whether fields are optional!
For example, with this type:
type Input = {
  a: {
    b?: string,
    c: {
      xx: 'removed',
      d?: string
    }
  },
  yy: { removed: true },
  xx: 'im removed'
};

the result of DeepRemoveProps<Input, 'xx' | 'yy'> is exactly the same as above, with all properties required - for some reason, Input['a']['b'] and Input['a']['c']['d'] are not having their ? preserved. I was under the impression that the mapped type used in DeepRemoveProps would by default preserve whether or not a ? is present.
How can I implement DeepRemoveProps in such a way that it preserves whether fields are optional?

You need to use a homomorphic mapped type, that iterates with in keyof T directly and  not in Exclude<keyof T, P>. You can use key remapping to filter out keys while keeping the homomorphic mapped type; see this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a duplicate. If not, what's missing?

That's just what I'm looking for, bravo! And thanks for the term "homomorphic"; I now understand that keyof T must appear without transformation in order for the ts compiler to apply the "optional-ness" of T's properties!

If you want a mapped type to preserve the optional and readonly modifiers for properties you're mapping over, you need to write a homomorphic mapped type (see What does "homomorphic mapped type" mean?) of the form {[⋯ in keyof T]: ⋯} for generic T, where in keyof appears directly. You have in Exclude<keyof which breaks it.  (TypeScript needs to know what the original type is, in order to copy property modifiers. If it sees in keyof T it will understand you're copying from T. But if the key set after in is some arbitrary type that merely depends on keyof T somewhere, it can't be sure.)
My suggestion would be to use key remapping with as and filter out keys in the as clause instead of the in clause.  That is, use Exclude to act on K and not keyof T:
type DeepRemoveProps<T, P extends string> = T extends object ? {
    [K in keyof T as Exclude<K, P>]: DeepRemoveProps<T[K], P>
} : T;

This maps any key K that overlaps with P to never, which has the effect of suppressing the key from the output.  Now your code should behave as expected:
type Result = DeepRemoveProps<Input, 'xx' | 'yy'>;
/* type Result = {
    a: {
        b?: string | undefined;
        c: {
            d?: string | undefined;
        };
    };
} */

Playground link to code
